# How to speed up and parallelize the following matlab code in the most efficient way possible?

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

Using `matlab`, I am trying to find a set of six integers, *x, y, z, a, b, c* that would satisfy the following equation:

*x^a + y^b = z^c*

```
min_num = 1; max_num = 100;
[x, y, z, a, b, c] = deal(zeros(min_num, max_num));

n=1;
for x_ = min_num:max_num
    for y_ = min_num:max_num
        for z_ = min_num:max_num
            for a_ = min_num:max_num
                for b_ = min_num:max_num
                    for c_ = min_num:max_num
                        if x_^a_ + y_^b_ == z_^c_
                            x(n)=x_; y(n)=y_; z(n)=z_; a(n)=a_; b(n)=b_; c(n)=c_;
                            n=n+1;
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
Pyth=[x',y',z', a',b',c'];
disp(Pyth)
```

Here is my first attempt to do the job:

```
min_num = 1; max_num = 10;


% simSpace is the size of the space you're exploring
simSpace = [max_num, max_num, max_num, max_num, max_num, max_num];
% calculate the total number of simulations
numSims  = prod(simSpace);

% pre-allocate data
data = zeros(numSims, max_num+1);

parfor idx = 1:numSims
    % convert scalar index into subscripts
    [i, j, k, l, m, n] = ind2sub(simSpace, idx);
    if i^l + j^m == k^n
        disp([i, j, k, l, m, n])
    end
end
```

However, I am wondering if I can do a better job.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? I strongly recommend that you reconsider your approach.

Comment: @beaker, how? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: We don't know what you're actually trying to achieve. Generating all the possibilities is almost never a good solution.

Comment: I have other conditions that remove most of those possibilities. This is just a MWE.

Comment: I suggest you use a much lower limit for the powers a,b,c to avoid the numbers becoming huge. Then see if the cth root of (x^a + y^b) is an integer.

Comment: As @Simon suggests, you won't be able to hold the values you're suggesting in a double, or even a uint64. The largest exponent of two that you can store is 63. The largest exponent of 100 is 10. But I disagree with taking any roots and expecting them to be integers. Observe that x^a, y^b and z^c all have the same range of possible values. Generate the set of values, sum all combinations, and check if the sums are in the set.